# Is there a way to know if there is a IWin32Window already created?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to integrate my application with several others.
In one case I am getting the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
Message=SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application.
```

This exception is because i am trying to do:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

And the application I am trying to integrate with has already created some IWin32Window.

I have searched around and what I get is that I basically should not try to `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)` if there is already a IWin32Window.
But since my application is going to be integrated in various others the conditions in each case change.

For now I am planning to change my application to receive a parameter so depending on the context I could run the `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)` or not.

But I would like, instead, to know if there is a way that I could verify if there is already a IWin32Window created before doing `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)`.

I am sorry if this is a dumb question but I haven't really worked much with Winforms before.

I would appreciate any help you can give me.

**Update**

After reading the first answer and some of the comments, I want to mention that the context where I am having this problem is rather complex and I can not completely explain it here. I appreciate the feedback and I understand what you are saying.

I think the spirit of my question was misunderstood by the context I added, I know why the error is happening and I know ways to solve it and get a work around.

I just would like to know if there is a way to know if there is an IWin32Window already created?

After all, the exception is happening because the IWin32Window is already created, so I was wondering how can you know that.

Thanks again.

Comment: You could just put the call in a try/catch, since you don't know much about the context your code will be used in.

Comment: It is very unclear why you are having trouble with this.  It should be called immediately in the Main() method.  No reasonable scenario where a window could have been created before this.  If it is "integrated" then it shouldn't call the method at all since you are no longer in control of the process configuration.

Comment: @Andy I am considering that, wouldn't it cause any problem though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to know if a IWin32Window was already created in my context (the framework doesn't offer it).

The only possible work around, is having your own Custom Form that inherits from Winforms Form. That way you can get when the forms are being created.

I can not do that, because my app gets integrated with many other, and I could not force them all to use other than Windows Form.

By setting:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

We were trying to save some time to the applications we were integrating with, however when we started having this error we removed the code, and stablished they should be the ones to configure the compatibility settings.

Answer (score 3):

Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault() is just *one* aspect of getting a program configured properly to display UI.  There's far more important stuff that needs to be setup correctly, the kind of initialization that a DLL can **never** take care of.  Super-duper important to have the main thread of such a program to be an STA thread, configured by the [STAThread] attribute on the Main() entrypoint of the EXE.  It needs to pump a message loop, Application.Run() to keep windows alive, that call can only be made once on a thread.

Duties that an EXE must perform, it cannot reliably be done by a DLL.  Starting a separate UI thread is a possibility, albeit a good way to cause lots more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

I have to check each static variables for the forms to make sure they set to null at the beginning, and create instance after SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault()

before:

```
public static FormMessage s_formShutdownMsg = new FormMessage(); //somewhere in the project
```

after:

```
static void Main()
       {
            public static Form1 s_mainForm = null;
            try
            {

                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

                s_formShutdownMsg = new FormMessage();
                s_mainForm = new Form1();
                Application.Run(s_mainForm);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
      }
public static FormMessage s_formShutdownMsg = null; //somewhere in the project
```