# vb.net running a exe in memory

Tags: vb.net, memory

I'm trying to run a app on memory but I'm having error at Invoke. What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to do this but in vb.net

Code C#

```
 // read the bytes from the application exe file
  FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
  BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
  byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
  fs.Close();
  br.Close(); 


// load the bytes into Assembly
Assembly a = Assembly.Load(bin);
// search for the Entry Point
MethodInfo method = a.EntryPoint;
if (method != null)
{
    // create an istance of the Startup form Main method
    object o = a.CreateInstance(method.Name);
    // invoke the application starting point
    method.Invoke(o, null);
}
```

in vb:

```
Dim instance As FileStream = File.Open("teste.exe", FileMode.Open)
Dim br As New BinaryReader(instance)
Dim bin As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(instance.Length))
instance.Close()
br.Close()
Dim a As Assembly = Assembly.Load(bin)
Dim metodo As MethodInfo = a.EntryPoint
If (IsDBNull(metodo) = False) Then
    'create an istance of the Startup form Main method
    Dim o As Object = a.CreateInstance(metodo.Name)
    'invoke the application starting point
    metodo.Invoke(o, Nothing)
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Nao encontrado")
End If
```

UPDATE:

I found the answer. I created the "test.exe" like a ConsoleAplication, than in the module I code

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim Form1 As New Form1
        Form1.Show()
        Do Until Form1.Visible = False
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
    End Sub
End Module
```

Then I changed from ConsoleApplication to Windowsform And create my Form1. And this

```
metodo.Invoke(o, Nothing)
```

to this:

```
metodo.Invoke(Nothing, New Object() {})
```

Thank you guys for the support!

Comment: Isn't `Main` static? In that case you don't need an instance of `o`. Also, what error are you getting? What's the exception method?

Comment: I add some code (c#) and this is what I would like to do in vb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Main` method expects that you pass it the `args` parameter.  Your current call is not passing any parameters, so I'm expecting that you are getting the following error if it ever reaches that line:

> System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.

To fix it, just pass a one-element object array as the second parameter of the `method.Invoke`. Also, because the `Main` method is a static method, you don't need to do a `CreateInstance` before invoking the method.

So all you need is this:

```
metodo.Invoke(Nothing, New Object() {Nothing})
```

If, for some reason, you actually need pass values to the main's `args` parameter, you can do it like this:

```
metodo.Invoke(Nothing, New Object() {New String() {"param1", "param2"}})
```

Comment: Exception: "You must call SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault before the first IWin32Window object in the application creation."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484623/is-there-a-way-to-know-if-there-is-a-iwin32window-already-created

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the c# code works you mistranslated the null check.

The equivalent of 'if (method != null)' in vb.net is

```
If method IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim o = a.CreateInstance(method.Name)
    method.Invoke(o, Nothing)
End If
```

Comment: This way that error is show System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.